# Python List sorting by columns

Tags: python, arrays

If I had a list

```
['xxxx', 'oooo', 'xxxx', 'oooo'......etc]
```

which looks like

```
                                                (xxxx)

                                                (oooo)

                                                (xxxx)

                                                (oooo)
```

and the list could be as long as the user inputs,

how would I make a new list sorted by each column which would look like:

```
['xoxo', 'xoxo', 'xoxo', 'xoxo']
```

which would be

```
           (xoxo)

           (xoxo)

           (xoxo)

           (xoxo)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you essentially want to transpose a 2D array?

Comment: You start out by saying this is a list of strings, but then parentheses appear (indicating tuples?) and I end up having no idea what you want.  What does sorting have to do with anything?  What do *columns* have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
myList=['xxxx', 'oooo', 'xxxx', 'oooo']
print [''.join(element) for element in zip(*myList)]
```

**Output**

```
['xoxo', 'xoxo', 'xoxo', 'xoxo']
```

What you are looking for, is called, transposing an array. That can be achieved with [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) function.

Comment: Please use a different variable name.